# Using jQuery to edit Shopify variants

Tags: jquery, shopify, liquid

Alright so I'm trying to figure out how to make content appear and disappear based on the product variant someone chose, and with the help of some people here, I managed to get the jQuery code that I need to make content appear and disappear based on the selected choice in a dropdown menu, and it works perfectly outside of Shopify.  The only problem is that it won't work once I try to transfer it over to Shopify.

Here is the section of code on my Shopify page:

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="post">
        {% include 'bracelet-hair' %}<br>     
        {% include 'braid-style' %}<br>
            {% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
            <div id="product-variants">      
                <select id="product-select" name="id">
                    {% for variant in product.variants %}
                        <option value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div><!-- product variants -->
             {%include 'engraving' %}
```

and here is my engraving snippet, which is where my code and content is that I am trying to display. (the '269270608' below is my variant id)

```
<script>
$("#product-select").change(function(){
 var choice = $(this).val()

 if (choice == '269270608'){

//$('#checkbox').change(function(){
    $('#hide2').removeClass('hidden2');  //remove class here
//});

 }else{
    $('#hide2').removeClass().addClass('hidden2');  //else addclass
 }

});
</script>

<div id="hide2" class="hidden2">    
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" />Engraving?
        <br>    
    Engraving Message:
        <input type="text" name="engraving">
        <br>    
</div>
```

Not sure how big Shopify syntax is here, but I went to their forums with no luck.  I appreciate any help and if you need any more info let me know.

Comment: you probably don't want the script part inside the form, also is jQuery loaded as $ or jQuery when you included it?